# ModuleNotFound error shown when importing file from root on vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a vscode project with this structure

- /app

  - /labor

    - config.py
    - functions.py
  - config.py
  - testing.py

Notice that there are two config files, one under the labor folder and one under the app folder.
In functions.py I'm trying to import config.py under the app folder.

```
# note I need to add app. before config because if I don't it will think that I'm referencing the file under labor folder
import app.config as app_config
```

In testing.py I'm importing both files

```
import config as app_config
import labor.config as labor_config

print("test")
```

This is giving me a ModuleNotFound error.
The crazy part is, if I hold my CTRL key and click on "config" in app.config in the functions.py file, it will take me to the folder. So it is recognizing it. But somehow, when running the code, python isn't.

I created a repo here if you'd like to try it out:
https://github.com/jadeid91/testproject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you running testing in wrong place
if you want testing in app directory you have to use `import config` instead of `import app.config` in labor directory .py files and add `__init__.py` to labor to make sure python dont confused and give you labor.config

### testing.py

```
import config as app_config
import labor.config as labor_config
import labor.functions as labor_functions

print(app_config.MAIN_TABLE_ID)
print(labor_config.LABOR_TABLE_ID)
```

### labor/functions.py

```py
import config as app_config

# if I import config, it will take me to labor.config
# import config


def hello():
    print(app_config.MAIN_TABLE_ID)
```

### folder structure

- /app

  - /labor

    - __init__.py
    - config.py
    - functions.py
  - config.py
  - testing.py

Comment: That worked. However, when I hover over "config" in functions.py and CTRL click, it takes me to app/labor/config.py
How can i fix that to take me to app/config.py instead?

Answer (score 0):

add __ init__.py file in your labor folder.
Adding this will make python consider as 1 of the directories. so when you import, it will know where to look for and finds the file.

You need not do this for the other file as it is in the same directory as your testing.py

Comment: That didn't work. Please check linked repo above if you want to check for yourself.